# Counting using the TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, database, count, tableadapter

I'm doing a schoolproject involving C# and some basic DataBase operations. One of the operations I need is a record count, after a long time of searching I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried TabelAdapter.Rows.Count but for some reason that doesn't work.

Included is a part of my code:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int RecordCount = 0;
    try
    {
        vriendenkringDataSetTableAdapters.FriendsTableTableAdapter FTTA = new vriendenkringDataSetTableAdapters.FriendsTableTableAdapter();
        RecordCount = FTTA.Rows.Count();
        FTTA.Insert(RecordCount, NicknameTextBox.Text, BirthdayTimePicker.Value, EmailTextbox.Text, 100, Convert.ToBoolean(1));
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(RecordCount));
        MessageBox.Show("Friend added succefully");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(RecordCount));
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Regards,
Rick

Comment: It has been a long time since I have worked with TableAdapters. Those are the visual tables in Visual Studio right? Perhaps you should move to Linq? Could you show more from `FriendsTableTableAdapter` which seems just like an empty adapter which does not persist or load from an actual table/db

Comment: TableAdapters are meant to *load* data into DataTables, not count them. Where's the DataTable? Your code is initializing a new adapter, never loads or inserts anything and yet tries to get a row count

Comment: Have you read the docs Rick? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171919.aspx

Comment: At first, thanks for the responses. (Sorry I was at work the last couple of hours). Furthermore, yes I have read the docs, but since I have a pretty small amount of knowledge in C# it wasn't very clear to me. But I have to turn this in in about 2 hours... my own fault for starting too late. At least thanks for trying to help me but I'm guessing I'm a bit of a lost cause

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you're just missing one part.

When you create a table adapter (In design mode), it's actually creating two things - the Adapter, and the "Data Table". In your original code, you've created the "Adapter", what we can consider to be the "Connection to the database". You need to create a Data Table, so you can store the data somewhere, by default, you should see this in your intellisense (the code prediction helper in visual studio) - without the words "Adapter" in it.

Once you have both objects created, you'll use the table adapters "Fill" method. Using your code, an example is below:

```
try   
{
   vriendenkringDataSetTableAdapters.FriendsTableTableAdapter FTTA = new vriendenkringDataSetTableAdapters.FriendsTableTableAdapter();

   // This is the new "Data Table" we're creating. 
   vriendenkringData.FriendsTableDataTable FTDT = new  vriendenkringData.FriendsTableDataTable(); 

   // We're now telling our Adapter to connect, get the data, and put it in our Data Table (Named FTDT above). 

   FTTA.Fill(FTDT); 

   MessageBox.Show(FTDT.Count()); //Note - Message box know's to convert the number to a string without you calling "Count.ToString()" :) 
   MessageBox.Show("Friend added succefully");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
    // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(RecordCount)); 
}
```